# How to read two characters at once from one string and copy into another

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to read two consecutive characters from one string and pass two by two characters to another string. The code is below but it gives me segmentation fault! What am I doing wrong?

```
char *st = malloc(16*sizeof(char));
char *string = "purpleredblue";
int i;
int x=0;

while(x<=16)
{
    for(i=x;i<=x+2;i++)
    {
        *st++=*string++;  //copies content from string to st
    }
    x+=2;
}

printf("%s\n",st);
```

Comment: a) `free()` is not optional. b) You´re incrementing st and string 3 times in the inner loop, and this whole loop runs infinitely because of the outer loop. There are not that many chars. Even with the x´=2 in the right position, it won´t work (24 instead of 14...) c) Describe what you really want more detailed.

Comment: Why can't you just use `memcpy`?  And why are you trying to copy 16 bytes into a space you explicitly allocate as 15 bytes, from one that is only 14 bytes long?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I really want is that this programs takes the string = "purplerebblue" and then pass just "pu" for st. Then, as the loop goes on, it passes "rp", then "le" and so on until the end of string

Comment: I've just edited the post and put the x+2 inside the loop and malloc now allocates 16*sizeof(char).But now I get munmap_chunk() invalid pointer...

Comment: Your `i` probably goes beyond the maximum index, which is **15**. Pretty trivial to find out by printing the values of `i`. But it would be more sane to stop copying at the end of the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong. This might help:

```
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
char *source = "purpleredblue";

char *dst = buffer;
char *src = source;
char *end = source + strlen(source);

while (src <= end)
{
    strncpy(dst, src, 2);

    dst += 2;
    src += 2;
}

printf("%s", buffer);
```

Comment: Someone must be hating me for the -1.